# Easy Get Node to wait (really) for a service

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I want to force Node to wait for the promise to complete (either by failure or success). So far, I'm not seeing what I wanted. I'm trying to wait for two web services to complete before merging, and especially before the function ends.

I've tried these two approaches below. In both cases, Node refuses to wait.

Approach 1:

```
function getStrategy() {
   // this is a web service that takes a few ms to run,
   // but so far I haven't seen any evidence that it bothers.
}

function getConfig() {
    // Both strategy and jwt are set to Promises
    const strategy = getStrategy();
    const jwt = getJwt(); 
    const lodash = require('lodash');
    var config = {};
    try {
    Promise.all([strategy,jwt])
    .then(data => { config = lodash.merge(config,data)})
    } catch(error) {
    console.log(' Print error message');
    }
    return config;
}
```

Approach 2:

```
function getStrategy() {
   // this is a web service that takes a few ms to run,
   // but so far I haven't seen any evidence that it bothers.
}

async function getConfig() {
    // Both strategy and jwt are set to Promises
    const strategy = getStrategy();
    const jwt = getJwt(); 
    const lodash = require('lodash');
    var config = {};

    try {
      var promiseResult = await Promise.all([strategy, jwt]);
      const lodash = require('lodash');
      config = lodash.merge(config, strategy[0]);
      config = lodash.merge(config, jwt);
    } catch (reason) {
      console.error('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
      console.error(reason);
      console.error("in getConfig(): Could not fetch strategy or jwt");
      console.error('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
    }
    return config;
}
```

I wish approach 2 worked, but it does not. It will not print any console.log statements after the call to Promise.all. So within that function it does wait. Except that it because I told it to "await", I have to make the function async. That allows Node to say, "oh, it's an async function, I can just go off and do something else and completely ignore the await keyword." It does this by returning to the function calling getConfig().

In the first approach, neither the "then" handler, nor any exceptions are thrown. It just impatiently leaves the function and goes back to the caller.

How do I get the thread that calls the getConfig() function to wait for the result. I mean really wait, not like, partially "await". Or, throw an exception and let me handle that. I'm finding that in Node, as soon as something because asynchronous, I have no idea how to get the await, or the then handler to work.

Updated attempt:
I separated the two service calls to individually control each service. I now have

```
async function getSynchronousStrategy(isVaultAvailable) {
  const secretsVaultReader = require('./src/configuration/secretsVaultReader');
  const secretsConfigReader = require('./src/configuration/secretsConfigReader');
  const strategy = isVaultAvailable
    ? secretsVaultReader.getStrategy()
    : secretsConfigReader.getStrategy();
  await strategy;
  console.log('@@ strategy after await=' + strategy);
  return strategy; ''
}

...
      const strategy = await getSynchronousStrategy(isVaultAvailable);
      console.log('@@@ strategy =' + JSON.stringify(strategy));
...
```

In the above case, Node sees the await strategy, but then prints
"@@ strategy after await=[object Promise]"
However, the second await seems to work, and it prints the desired strategy. I'm guessing the promise was eventually settled and it was able to print the result. I don't mind the time, I *just* *want* *it* to wait.

Obviously, it did *not* wait. It

Comment: May be worth read https://www.infoq.com/presentations/profile-nodejs/.

Comment: @RichardRublev Not sure if this was the intent, but it did give me a chuckle :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply using await with both the function calls directly, in this manner it will wait for both the functions to return responses before proceeding further.

Comment: Thanks; you mean making getConfig() async and doing await on that too?

Comment: I tried making getConfig async and doing await on that function and it still refused to wait.

Comment: I meant trying this **const strategy = await getStrategy();
    const jwt = await getJwt();**

Comment: I have const jwt = isVaultAvailable ? await secretsVaultReader.getJwtSecret() : await secretsConfigReader.getJwtSecret(); /* still returns a promise */ const jwt; /* does not do anything. Then the caller does an await on that promise again. */ Multiple awaits seem to help because it seems to ignore at least one of them.